# How do I get tensorboard to work with sagemaker studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Currently playing around with tensorboard on Sagemaker studio. According to aws, it is supposedly possible. However, I keep encountering error code 500 after launching tensorboard and changing the file path to ...../proxy/{port number}

Great if somebody can assists on this topic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this step by step guide on how to enable TensorBoard on SageMaker Studio here: https://github.com/anoop-ml/smstudio_tensorboard_sample

Did you follow those instructions?

Comment: Didn't realise it is the system terminal and not the image terminal. Thanks :)